Stack Double problem where answer should be only one
Question:
$7$ men labeled $A−G$ play a coin flip game that starts with player $A$. At each turn, the player will flip a coin. If it appears heads, then the player must double the stack of each other player that plays the game, taking the money from their own stack. In other words, the payout to each of the other 6 players is the value of their current stack. Otherwise, nothing happens. The sequence $HHHHHHH$ is observed and each of the $7$ players ends up with $\$1.28$ as their final stack. If $x_1,...,x_7$ represent the amount that each player started with, find the value of $10000(x_1^2+...+x_7^2)$.
I tried to take an example of $3$ men ending up with $\$2$ each, then tried to backtrack the situation.
$$
\begin{align*}
& [3]: 2\space\space |2\space\space |2 \\
& [2]:2+1-a\space\space |2+a\space\space |1 \\
& [1]:3 -a+b\space\space |\frac{2+a}{2}\space\space |1+\frac{2+a}{2}-b \\
& [0]:\frac{3-a+b}{2}\space\space |\frac{2+a}{2} -c\space\space |1+\frac{2+a}{2}-b+\frac{3-a+b}{2}+c
\end{align*}
$$
Here (due to lack of knowledge in LaTex), by $[s]: x|y|z$ means the state $s$ of the stack of 3 men with values $x, y, z$. Note that the $[0]$ state is the initial state.
Note that $a, b, c$ are positive values that can be chosen from anything in some range. Now, if I choose $a=1,b=1,c=0.5$, the initial state will be $3/2,1,7/2$, and if I choose $a=2,b=1,c=1$, the initial state will be $1,1,4$. Clearly, if I square and add these numbers (initial stack values), I will not end up with the same value. What makes $7$ men and $\$1.28$ as final state make the initial state unique? I am saying this as this problem can be found here and expects one answer only.
Please let me know if you find my explanation odd. I will try to make it more explainable.

$128 = 2^7$. For three man, try them ending up with 8 cents each.

@user58697 No, you're not taking into account that player X pays out the rest. IE with 3 men, the prior step is $ 64, 64, 256$, and the prior step is $32,   224, 128$, and the starting value is thus $208  , 112, 64$.

After $2$ flips in your example both A and B must have $1$ because they get doubled on the last flip.  C must have $4$ to be able to pay them both and end with $2$.  There is no uncertainty.  Then after $1$ flip A must have $0.5$ and C must have $2$, so B must have $3.5$.  After $0$ flips C must have $1$ and B must have $1.75$, leaving $3.25$ to A.
Here is my computation of each stack after each flip.  I believe the $\$1.28$ was just chosen to have enough factors of two that the pennies do not get split.  If the players aside from the one that is doubling stacks have $p$ between them and the one that is paying will have $q$ after paying we have $2p+q=896$ and the one that is paying will have $p+q=(896+q)/2$


Any idea why $~1.28$~$ was chosen, rather than $~128$~?$

@user2661923:  None.  The problem is linear, so it will scale with the final amount.  The factor of $10000$ in the final computation is to get rid of the decimals after squaring.

See also the comments following this answer that (very plausibly) suggest that the intended unit of measure is dollars rather than pennies.

Measure value in pennies.
The total amount of all people combined, which never changes, is $~7 \times 2^7.~$
Index the people A thru G as $~P_1, \cdots, P_7.~$
For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\},$ 
in the coin flips that follow coin flip $~k,~$ person $~P_k~$ will have his amount multiplied by $~2^{7-k},~$ and will then end up with $~2^7.~$
Therefore, immediately after coin flip $~k,~$ person $~P_k~$ must have the amount $~2^k.~$
Therefore, immediately after coin flip $~k,~$ everyone other than $~P_k~$ must have had a combined amount of
$$(7 \times 2^7) - 2^k.$$
Therefore, the combined amount before coin flip $~k,~$ of all of the other people, must have been $~(7 \times 2^{6}) - 2^{k-1}.~$
Therefore, on coin flip $~k,~$ person $~P_k~$ must have lost $~(7 \times 2^{6}) - 2^{k-1}.~$
Therefore, before coin flip $~k,~$ person $~P_k~$ must have had
$$2^k + (7 \times 2^6) - 2^{k-1} = (7 \times 2^6) + 2^{k-1}.$$
Since this is the amount that person $~P_k~$ had before coin flip $~k,~$ then there must have been $~(k-1)~$ prior coin flips that each doubled the amount that person $~P_k~$ had.
Therefore,
$$x_k = \frac{(7 \times 2^6) + 2^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}} = (7 \times 2^{7-k}) + 1.$$
Therefore,
$$(x_k)^2 = [ ~49 \times 2^{14 - 2k} ~] + [ ~14 \times 2^{7 - k} ~] + 1.$$
Note that
$$2^{12} + 2^{10} + \cdots + 2^0 = \frac{1}{3} \times [ ~2^{13} + 2^{12} + 2^{11} + 2^{10} + \cdots + 2^1 + 2^0 ~] = \frac{2^{14} - 1}{3}.$$
Further, $~2^{6} + 2^{5} \cdots + 2^{0} = 2^{7} - 1.$
Therefore, setting
$$A = (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 + \cdots + (x_7)^2$$
then
$$A = \left[ ~49 \times \frac{2^{14} - 1}{3} ~\right] + \left[ ~14 \times ( ~2^{7} - 1 ~) ~\right] + 7.$$
So, the desired computation is
$$10000 \times A.$$

Side note: OP is working in dollar, and you are working in pennies. So the actual answer is just your calculated $A$.

@CalvinLin You are probably right.  This never occurred to me, and I did find the $~10000~$ scalar odd.  However, my standard approach is to base my interpretation of the posted question on the excerpted question's specific wording.  In this situation, the question was ambiguous, so I choose to work in pennies, to guarantee that $~A~$ itself is an integer.

@CalvinLin In other words, assuming that your interpretation is correct (and I suspect that it is), why in the world didn't the problem composer specify that each person ended up with $~128$~$ instead of $~1.28$.~$  What is the educational value in the $~1.28$ ~$ messiness coupled with having to apply the $~10^5~$ scalar?

Correction, in previous comment, should be $~10^4~$ scalar.
